# How to deal with cockroach at home?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen, personal-care, pest-control

Recently, in the past few months, I found and killed some (~4) cockroaches at home, I'm worried that there is actually more cockroaches, I've tried putting Roach Baits in the kitchen, bathroom etc. but the cockroaches are clever enough to know that it's a trap made by human, so it didn't help very much, so, is there any way to kill the remaining cockroaches?

I cleaned the floor nearly every day, didn't left any food overnight and tried to keep the house as clean and dry as possible, but the cockroaches still exists.

Comment: Down voted due to lack of [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=control%20cockroaches) and clarity (we don't even know what kind of roaches they are). Flagged to close as not needing a lifehack, since it has not been made clear why other standard pest control methods (even e.g. calling an exterminator) beyond one arbitrary brand of roach bait are not acceptable. Pest control is a well-studied problem and non-hack resources exist to solve it. "Hacks" here are likely to just be less-than-useful "tips" ultimately resulting in proper pest control methods anyways.

Comment: Boric acid can help you get rid of the cockroaches. Pour it along the perimeter of the room(s) and near the sources of water. Cockroaches should be gone in about a week.

Comment: @deville Feel free to post that as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of household products that you can pick up that are supposed to kill roaches and prevent them from returning.  If you pick up a spray, spray it in any little crevice you can find.  Around and underneath your stove/refrigerator/dishwasher/shelves/cabinets/etc. Any little crack between your walls/floors and anything else.  Get every area they could possible squeeze into because they are very difficult (at best) to get rid of if they find a place they like.  Also, spray around the outside of your building if it is a single residence.

I don't know if it works for cockroaches, but an unbroken line of cinnamon or baking powder in your window sills is supposed to stop ants. These are usually fairly cheap to buy and may be worth a shot.  Same with peppermint oil.  A cotton-ball with peppermint oil on it around your foundation is supposed to stop ants from coming into your house.  Probably because of the sugar content drawing them to that instead of your house, but it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm worried that there is actually more cockroaches.

Yes, you have roaches, and there are most certainly more.

You will want call an exterminator. Consumer grade traps will have limited effect (especially if you do not have the expertise needed to identify the type of roach). Foggers may have a longer lasting but still temporary effect. Silly little tricks may kill a few here and there or fend a few off for a few hours or days, but if you are asking on Lifehacks then it is unlikely that you are properly equipped to wage a war against one of the most successful and resilient species of life on the planet.

As a hack, pay a stranger on the street to call the exterminator for you. This is a life hack because it is an unorthodox use of a stranger.

Comment: Downvoted - you've already left a negative comment against the question. Here you a clearly adding a pointless "hack" at the end because you really just wanted to leave a snarky comment.

Comment: @Dave If you see multiple cockroaches, you have more cockroaches, and you'll want to call an exterminator as you won't be able to get rid of them on your own. Nothing snarky or incorrect about that part, at least. That's just how cockroaches work.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to pet a cat in your home (if you're pretty tired of killing roaches). In my case, my cat monitors for any movement on the floor/wall and chases when cockroaches found.

Comment: My cat never helps out that. I think only few cats do that.

Comment: My boss has a cat. She ended up being completely infested with worms. He suspects that eating roaches did that...

Comment: A cat may catch one here and there but will not be able to counter the quantity that roaches generally exist in. Also a cat is very likely to eventually just get bored. Cats are great for mice, but not so much roaches or other pests that exist in large numbers with great persistence. Roaches are also much more capable of escaping a cat due to their small size and ability to climb walls.